# the communication from one app to another app in iphone

Tags: iphone

My questions ..Development in  IPHONE

consider two applications  APP_A and APP_B..

APP_A wants to send message to APP_B and vice versa.... for communicating like this what is the best approach ...

the communication should be done ..

in watsapp the communication is done by members like . friend_1 and friend_2 sends msgs ..

like the same..but my requirement is  one module in APP_A wants to send message to one Module in APP_B or vice versa...

can any one please tell me the best approach to do in IPHONE development

Answer (score 1):

I am not certain what you are asking and what you mean by sending messages, but if you are talking about sharing data then you can use a shared pasteboard (from iOS 7) or shared keychain items. This is assuming that the apps are from the same developer.

If you are asking about opening another app, have a look at URL schemes.